# Use javax.smartcardio for MIFARE Classic and Omnikey 5021 CL

Tags: java, rfid, mifare, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

Can the API `javax.smartcardio` be used on for finding the smart card terminal for the card reader Omnikey 5021 CL and to read sectors of a MIFARE Classic card? This needs to work on a Windows 7 computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this reader supports PC/SC 2.0 and is, thus, accessible through `javax.smartcardio`. You can access MIFARE Classic cards through the PC/SC extensions for contactless storage cards.

See the [PC/SC specification](http://www.pcscworkgroup.com/specifications/files/pcsc3_v2.01.09.pdf) for standard commands (load keys, general authenticate, read binary, update binary) and the [Omnikey contactless developer guide](http://www.hidglobal.com/sites/hidglobal.com/files/resource_files/5321-903_b.4_omnikey_contactless_developer_guide_en.pdf) for additional commands and for keyslots usable for authentication with MIFARE Classic keys.